# How to find integer in container which stores pointers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, find, std

A container stores pointers to integers. I would like to find integer=66 using normal variable.
When I am trying to do this by pointer it is ok.
Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int *a=new int(22);
    int *b=new int(44);
    int *c=new int(66);

    int d = 66;

    vector<int*> v1;
    v1.push_back(a);
    v1.push_back(b);
    v1.push_back(c);

    std::vector<int*>::iterator it;
    // it = find (v1.begin(), v1.end(), c); // Ok.
    it = find (v1.begin(), v1.end(), d);
    if (it != v1.end())
    {
        std::cout << "Element found in myvector: " << **it << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Element not found in myvector\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to use find_if() function.

Comment: Why are you using pointers as vector items in 1st place? If you want to use `find_if()` you neet to pass a comparator function that dereferences the pointers.

Comment: Before go further, understand what pointer are: comments like "c is a pointer, d is a variable" are nonsense and reval a poor understanding of the conceptas behind.

Comment: std::find compares the data type of the container, in this case a pointer. So you are not comparing the value '66' but a memory address. As mentioned before, use std::find_if instead or change your inner type to int.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) like this:

```
std::find_if(
    std::begin(pointer_vec), std::end(pointer_vec), 
    [](const int *p){return p != nullptr && *p == 66;});
```

Comment: It's actually not such a good point. Lambda's are designed to be used as small, anonymous functors, defined directly in the scope where they're used. In that scope (`vector<int*> v1;`  above) there are no null pointers. If you'd write a named function, usable throughout you code, it would make sense to check for `nullptr` though.

Comment: I personally disagree. I think that the deciding factors for lambda vs. name are reusability, clarity, and succinctness. Javascript uses quite large lambda functions very effectively. When lambdas started showing up in C++ "coming attraction" blog posts, I was first put off by examples where a ``for_each`` would be extended by ~10 locs *within the argument*. Exposure to Javascript changed that for me.  Maybe it's a subjective matter.

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can do this:

```
it = find_if (v1.begin(), v1.end(), [d](int* p){ return *p == d; });
```